# How to install METIS on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, metis

I want to install the METIS package on ubuntu.

I tried the instructions on the install.txt file which says  to use

```
$ make install
```

which I did, after installing make as well.

I also tried the

```
sudo apt-get install metis
```

which installed it successfully but

when trying to use it in both cases I get

```
metis.h: No such file in directory compilation terminated
```

In case anyone asks I use g++ -I/path/to/file myprogram.cpp to specify the path where metis.h is.

I believe I haven't done something correct in the installation but I can't determine what it is.

Can someone help me with the installation process?

Comment: can you show us the result of `locate metis.h` ? On my system I get only a `metis.hpp` after installing such a package, which would explain why the include doesn't help you.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `sudo apt-get install libmetis-dev`.

Answer (score 2):

BUILD.txt file from metis:

> Building METIS requires CMake 2.8, found at http://www.cmake.org/, as
>   well as GNU make. Assumming CMake and GNU make are installed, two
>   commands should suffice to build metis:

```
 $ make config
 $ make
```

so, i tried not directly on ubuntu, but on my mac and it works in that order. 
after the two make command i have the following folder strucure:

```
build
-Darwin-x86_64 (the build architecture)
 -libmetis
   -libmetis.a
 -programs
   -gpmetis
    ...
```

after you can call

```
make install
```

I make a little test example and it works. You are maybe interest in my CMake-File. This could be the solution for your problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (MetisTest)
include_directories("/usr/local/include")
link_directories("/usr/local/lib")
add_executable(metisTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(metisTest metis)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may append your metis installation path to the environment variable CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. For example, in your ~/.bashrc, add:

`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/metis/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`

then,

`source ~/.bashrc`

Please see more in the question [Linux could not find metis.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52366401/6506935).