# Linux could not find metis.h

Tags: linux, path, include, metis

I am trying to install Metis. Since I am working on a public server, I couldn't install it as a root user. So I have installed metis in my account  /home/jd/metis.

When I try to execute something, I get

fatal error: metis.h: No such file or directory

I guess the system looks for metis.h under /usr/local/include but couldnt find it there. How do I make linux look for metis.h under /home/jd/metis/include directory?

I added this path to the $PATH variable. But still the same error.
Please advise.

Comment: `*.h` files are typically only used by a compiler.  Perhaps you need to add the directory to `CPATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to work with cmake. In this question:[install metis on unbuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046189/how-to-install-metis-on-ubuntu/41336362#41336362), I wrote down my cmake file.  The command

```
include_directories("/home/jd/metis/include")
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. 
For example, add this kind of statement in your ~/.bashrc:

`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/metis/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`,

then,

`source ~/.bashrc`

As for dynamic link library(when you install other library such as libevent locally), you may want to change the following two environment variables:

`export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libevent/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libevent/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`