# How to compile METIS 5?

Tags: fortran, metis

I am working on a system that needs to use [METIS's API](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview). My question is how build Metis for my system.

The older versions of Metis e.g. version 4.0.2, just has everything in one folder (lib) and you run `make` in that folder.

The newest version of Metis has many folders: libs, include, gklib, and others.

The documentation shows how to use the interface, but doesn't show how to compile it in my system.

Do I have to compile the whole library as if it were a stand-alone program, or is there another way to compile it and build as an interface?

Comment: Where did you get the source code? Is there any README or similar file in the package?

Comment: The web page you linked contains this *"To build METIS, follow the instructions in the file metis-5.x.y/Install.txt."* Have you read that file?

Comment: i did read the file before the post. the file has information on how to build the standalone program, but has nothing about the how to include the API in your program which is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just follow the instructions in the BUILD.txt file:

```
make config
make
make install
```

it is as simple as that. (yes, it will build the standalone program AND the API)

Comment: /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/abdul/MYPROG/customized2/metis/build/Linux-x86_64/CMakeFiles 0
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'w'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/abdul/MYPROG/customized2/metis/build/Linux-x86_64'
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abdul/MYPROG/customized2/metis'
makefile:420: recipe for target 'metis' failed
make: *** [metis] Error 2

Comment: Thanks for the tip. when i do that, i get this error. and i don't know what the "w" is. When i compile metis outside my program, it works perfectly.

Comment: you should compile metis outside your program and then link your program against the compiled metis lib. There is no need to build it together with your code. Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046189/how-to-install-metis-on-ubuntu